# <App/> component is not rendering in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I don't know where is the issue is arriving. struggling a lot but still my  component is not rendering in React.js. it's just showing white screen and nothing else.

Cards.jsx

```
import React from "react";

function Card(props){
return (
    <>
    <img src={props.imgsrc} alt="mypic"/>
    <h1>{props.title}</h1>
    </>
  )
}

export default Card;
```

App.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from "./Cards";
import Reportdata from "./Api";

const App = () => {
 <>
  {Reportdata.map(val=>{
    return (
     <Card
       key = {val.id}
       imgsrc = {val.image}
       title = {val.title}/>
       )
    })};
 </>
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'; 
import App from "./App.jsx";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
 root.render(
  <App />
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the return statement inside the **App** component:

```
const App = () => {
 return (
  <>
   {Reportdata.map(val=>{
    return (
     <Card
       key = {val.id}
       imgsrc = {val.image}
       title = {val.title}/>
       )
    })};
  </>
)}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to use the return statement make sure to remove the curly braces:

```
const App = () => (
  <>
   {Reportdata.map(val=>{
    return (
     <Card
       key = {val.id}
       imgsrc = {val.image}
       title = {val.title}/>
       )
    })};
  </>
)
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions?retiredLocale=it

Comment: hey thanks for comment, that was really stupid mistake... I should delete this question,

Comment: Your welcome :). If I helped please make sure to mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [@poal98](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15471452/poal98), you need a `return` statement. Or you could also get rid of the `{` `}` from the App Component:

```
const App = () => (
  <>
    {Reportdata.map((val) => {
      return <Card key={val.id} imgsrc={val.image} title={val.title} />;
    })}
    ;
  </>
);
```

> Here's a **[Working Sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-czzwaw?file=src%2FApp.js)**.